# Android real time ECG-type graphs in a PopupWindow

Tags: android, graphics, real-time

I have looked at some threads concerning real-time line drawing (for items like ECG traces) and all solutions are based upon the idea that the graph is the main activity. What I need is a popup situation where the line graph is drawn only when it is needed.

Can one attach a 'surface' to a PopupWindow? Right now I use an AlertDialog and invalidate() of a Canvas and that stinks as first it is not real time (the entire set of data is drawn then updated so one gets 'flashes' each update) and second the AlertDialog appears impossible to control the size of (same size both orientations) BUT I do see data displayed in the background behind the Dialog box in a scrolled ListView which is the main activity of the application.

I would even be happy if I could get real time drawing in the AlertDialog without this ugly invalidate() though the inability to specify its size is frustrating!